# Table border not supported in HTML5

Tags: css, html, border

Table border isn't supported in HTML5, but CSS will apply changes to all of my tables, instead of just 1, is there a way around?

I want to make one table to have borders but the "table border" option is not supported in HTML5, what should I do?

CSS will make changes to all of my tables, instead of just one... is there a way around it? :)

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: add a class to the one table you want to style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the border, I think you can do :

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* or, for each cell of your table */
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you want to add this style to only one table, then just add a class to this table, and instead in the css something like :

```css
.your-class {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Hope I could help,

Comment: ohhh! that's right, i forgot about classes and IDs, thank you! :)